# Set char set 1251 in OleDB connection string for DBF files

Tags: c#, character-encoding, oledb

I'm trying to read a dbf file with an OleDB. Everything works well except for the russian char set. I am trying to set encoding in connection string. My code is below

```
var dir = "F:\\Programmers\\";

DataTable result = new DataTable();

var conStr = $"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={dir};Extended Properties=\"dBase III;Character set=1251;\"";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
{
    conn.Open();

    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM 200901", conn);

    OleDbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

    result.Load(reader);
}
```

But nothing works! How to specify the char set correctly?

Comment: Try use `CharacterSet=1251;`

Comment: Hi, I tried set up "CharacterSet", "CharSet", "CODEPAGE". Did not help...

Comment: Maybe, you need to use 866 instead of 1251?

Comment: I'm sure the file encoding is 1251. The file was read correctly witn DotNetDbf library (encoding 1251). I tried to find a link to the documentation for specifying the encoding in the connection string, but found nothing :(

Comment: It is really strange. I used your code for reading from KLADR base. Data was read correctly even without `CharacterSet` specifying.

Comment: Can you send me an example of issue table (without private data)?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible to transfer a file using this resource. Could you please write your email

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221147/discussion-between-miamy-and-r00xus).